# What is the meaning of 心兴?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of 心兴 in the picture below (towards bottom left in image)? I am guessing it means *to think*, but doesn't 想 mean *to think*?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That character is not「兴」(*to rise* > *excited, happy*), it is「头」(*head*).

「心头」(literally *heart + head*) means *mind* - the picture is saying that you use your *mind* to think/reason.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this! I really confused those two characters.